# Required field Validation and Modal popup occurs at the same time

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit, modalpopupextender

I have a page where there are some text box with required fields and I have a submit button in the same page for which I have the Modal Pop up. When I click the submit button without filling the text box, the pop up is displayed and the error message is also displayed near the text box.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt_ExpiresBy"
             class="datePicker" 
             runat="server" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="req_ExpiresBy" 
                            ValidationGroup="SM" 
                            runat="server" 
                            ControlToValidate="txt_ExpiresBy" 
                            Text="*ExpiresBy is a required field.">
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<asp:Button ID="btn_Send" 
            runat="server" 
            ValidationGroup="SM" 
            Text="Send" 
            CausesValidation="true" 
            OnClick="Send_Click" />                         
<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" 
                        TargetControlID="btn_Send" 
                        PopupControlID="Pnl_ForgotPass" 
                        runat="server">
</asp:ModalPopupExtender>
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:Panel ID="Pnl_ForgotPass" runat="server" 
           CssClass="cpHeader">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="Btn_ViewDash" runat="server" 
                        Text="View DashBoard" />
            <asp:Button ID="Btn_SeeMessages" runat="server" 
                        Text="Messages Page" />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Panel>
```

I want to display the PopUp only after all the required fields are filled, but it displays before it. How to change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with some javascript.

First remove the `TargetControlID="btn_Send"` from `ModalPopupExtender1`

```
<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" 
                    PopupControlID="Pnl_ForgotPass" 
                    runat="server">
```

Then, Add those scripts at the end of the page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function ShowPopup() {
   $find('ModalPopupExtender1').Show();
  }

  function ValidateAndShowPopup() {
    if (Page_ClientValidate('SM')) {
        ShowPopup();
    }
  }
</script>
```

Then, bind the the OnClientClick event to the new script.

```
<asp:Button ID="btn_Send" 
        runat="server" 
        ValidationGroup="SM" 
        Text="Send" 
        CausesValidation="true" 
        OnClientClick="ValidateAndShowPopup()"  />
```

By the way, the `OnClick="Send_Click"` event was shallowed by the behavior of the ModalPopupExtender's `TargetControlID`, So I removed it.

Comment: how possible can it still work given that  The TargetControlID cannot be null now for modal popup extender

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use a hiddenfield for that purpose you can see a solution on

[ModalPopupExtender and Validation Controls](http://forums.asp.net/t/1173416.aspx/1/10).

Answer (score 0):

The summit button you have in the modal pop up needs to have this property

```
CausesValidation="false"
```

this property avoids the required fields to be fired when the modal popup summit/ok button is clicked